# SQL Server and vb.net bind picture from varbinary(max) column

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012

Asking all experts to please help me on how to bind `varbinary(max)` datatype from SQL Server to a form in vb.net. I have made a login page and authenticate the user to main page but I want to bind the avatar of the user to the main interface and all other info. Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking a clear question will make it easier to help you. Including the work that you've done until now and sharing  the error if there is any is very important. please read this article to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can only bind such a field to a property of type `Byte()`. You can't bind to, for instance, the `Image` property of a `PictureBox`, because the data is not an `Image`.  You need to write code to do it manually, without data-binding.